# Read Soap XML request in PHP Array

Tags: php, xml, laravel, soap

Good morning all,
I have been stuck on a piece of code for a while and decided to ask one of you and create an account on Stackoverflow. I hope you guys can help!

[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjOXm.png)
[Image 2, output on web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpaOX.png)

I need to read out the [exportResult] but I cannot get there. I can read it now as;

```
$administration = array('demo', ''); 
$soapclient = new SoapClient("https://www.cashweb.nl/?api/3.0/wsdl");
$theCall = $soapclient->export('', '','','','', $administration, '0');

var_dump($theCall); // all result
var_dump($theCall['exportResult'] // XML result
```

So, i tried to use:

```
$theCall['exportresult']['R0101'][0]['F0101'];
```

But that is not working. Can anyone help me out how I can read the F0101 tag?

Comment: What is the error actually?

Comment: In your array it seems you skipped the `cash` node

Comment: There is no error, @JimPanse when I try to call with cashcode there is no result.. This is the output on web (there are no tags such as <f0101>, only in the source. (I editted the post)